# how to generate a unique service id number in python using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello guys i have a data which have two cloumns so want to generate unique sequence of id for that...
**This is data:**

```
    Year    Month   
0   2010    Jan     
1   2010    Feb     
2   2010    Mar     
3   2010    Mar     
4   2010    Mar
```

**I want to join that service id to these two column for that i have write a code:**

```
data['Sr_ID'] = data.groupby(['Month','Year']).ngroup()
data.head()
```

**this give this output:**

```
Year    Month   Sr_ID
0   2010    Jan     20
1   2010    Feb     15
2   2010    Mar     35
3   2010    Mar     35
4   2010    Mar     35
```

but i don't want "Sr_ID" like this i want to be like **"Sr_0001...Sr_0002"**
it should be in a sequence of number this "Sr" so for this 
**I want a output like this:**

```
    Year    Month   Sr_ID
 0  2010    Jan     Sr_0001
 1  2010    Feb     Sr_0002
 2  2010    Mar     Sr_0003
 3  2010    Mar     Sr_0004
 4  2010    Mar     Sr_0005
```

I want to generate different id for different row because I have 8 columns, with no repeated rows.

Comment: Why does 2010-Mar in your desired output map to 3 different Sr_ID numbers?

Comment: @jpp sir i want to generate different id for different row coze i have 8 column other than this which is not same

Comment: Is any way to generate id number from our side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) + [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

You can use a range, then pad with zeros to the left:

```
df['Sr_ID'] = 'Sr_' + pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(df.index)+1)).astype(str).str.zfill(4)

print(df)

   Year Month    Sr_ID
0  2010   Jan  Sr_0001
1  2010   Feb  Sr_0002
2  2010   Mar  Sr_0003
3  2010   Mar  Sr_0004
4  2010   Mar  Sr_0005
```